# Как получить acess_token vk?

Tags: java, vkontakte-api

Нашел в интернете код, как авторизоваться в вк:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://oauth.vk.com/authorize?" +
    "client_id=" + client_id +
    "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri +
    "&display=" + display +
    "&response_type=" + response_type);
HttpResponse response = null;

try {
    response = httpClient.execute(post);
    System.out.println("Success"); //Пишет, запрос выполнен
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
post.abort();
String HeaderLocation = response.getFirstHeader("location").getValue();
```

однако моя среда не находит таких классов как `HttpPost` или `DefaultHttpClient`, я подумал и предположил что народ использует библиотеки апач. Скачал я их значит вот [тут](https://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi), и там я не обнаружил того, что искал. Как мне реализовать авторизацию вк с десктопного приложения? ну или где взять эти самые библиотеки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут расписано довольно популярно

https://vk.com/dev/authentication

Если кратко - создать standalone приложение, сгенерировать ссылку которая отправит пользователя на ВК, там он подтвердит права твоему предварительно созданному приложению на доступ к аккаунту пользователя, после чего ВК отправит запрос по твоему коллбэку с токеном авторизации для пользователя.